# Why are birefringence materials so rare?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, optical-materials, birefringence

By symmetry, most crystals will show birefringence. But the effect is very minute. So the question is actually, why is the birefrigence effect in most low-symmetry materials so small?

Comment: Small in comparison to what?

Answer (score 1):

Birefringence occurs when you have different bonding forces in different directions in the crystal. These different bonding forces lead to a different refractive index in each direction. In amorphous materials, there is not a preferred direction or crystal structure. Bonding forces are the same for every direction and this causes the material to have a single refractive index.

You can see a bi-axial crystal with 3 bonding forces and 3 different refractive indices.
[image]